# How to use refresh control inside a native-base tab?

Tags: reactjs, react-native, tabs, native-base

I have a native-base tab with a list inside in which I want to use a RefreshControl inside to refresh the list when pulled down however I just can't get it to work correctly. I have implemented the RefreshControl in several other places but it just wont run inside a tab for me.
Here is the code where the tabs are. It only works if I put it in the content tag here put if I try and include it in the tabs or inside the component being called nothing happens when you pull down.

```
render() {
    const { navigation } = this.props;
    return (
            <Container>
                <Content >
                    <Tabs locked= {true}>
                        <Tab heading="Active" >
                                <PharmacyActiveView screenProps={this.state.username} nav={navigation}/>
                        </Tab>
                        <Tab heading="Expired">
                               <PharmacyExpiredView screenProps={this.state.username} nav={navigation}/>
                        </Tab>
                    </Tabs>
                </Content>
            </Container>
    );
}
```

Here is the PharmacyActiveView code. I have tried including the refresh control in here but the onRefresh method never gets hit no matter what.

```
onRefresh() {
        this.setState(() => { return { pageNumber: 1, refreshing: true } }, () => {
            this.getActivePharmacyPrescriptions(this.state.pageNumber, global.defaultValues.pageSize, false);
        });
    }

render() {
        const footerStyle = this.state.metaData == undefined ? null : (this.state.metaData.HasNextPage ? style.footerViewActive : style.footerViewInactive);
        return (
            <View refreshControl={
                <RefreshControl
                    onRefresh={this.onRefresh.bind(this)}
                    refreshing={this.state.refreshing}
                    colors={[sharedStyle.mainColor]} //android
                    tintColor={sharedStyle.mainColor} //ios
                    progressBackgroundColor={'#fff'}
                />
            }>
                <FlatList
                    style={style.pharmacyFlatList}
                    data={this.state.data}
                    renderItem={this._renderItem}
                    keyExtractor={(x, i) => i}
                    extraData={this.state}
                />
            </View>
        );
    }
```

Let me know if you need any more info, I have just included the code I think is relevant. Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The Refresh Control has to be assigned to the refreshControl property of the Content component. Instead of having the Content at the High level, move it to the child components:

```
render() {
    const { navigation } = this.props;
    return (
        <Container>
            <Tabs locked= {true}>
                <Tab heading="Active" >
                    <PharmacyActiveView screenProps={this.state.username} nav={navigation}/>
                </Tab>
                <Tab heading="Expired">
                    <PharmacyExpiredView screenProps={this.state.username} nav={navigation}/>
                </Tab>
            </Tabs>
        </Container>
    );
}
```

Make sure that Content is the base/first component of each child element:

```
onRefresh() {
    this.setState(() => { return { pageNumber: 1, refreshing: true } }, () => {
        this.getActivePharmacyPrescriptions(this.state.pageNumber, global.defaultValues.pageSize, false);
    });
}

render() {
    const footerStyle = this.state.metaData == undefined ? null : (this.state.metaData.HasNextPage ? style.footerViewActive : style.footerViewInactive);
    return (
        <Content refreshControl={
            <RefreshControl
                onRefresh={this.onRefresh.bind(this)}
                refreshing={this.state.refreshing}
                colors={[sharedStyle.mainColor]} //android
                tintColor={sharedStyle.mainColor} //ios
                progressBackgroundColor={'#fff'}
            />
        }>
            <FlatList
                style={style.pharmacyFlatList}
                data={this.state.data}
                renderItem={this._renderItem}
                keyExtractor={(x, i) => i}
                extraData={this.state}
            />
        </Content>
    );
}
```

More details at:

[Native Base - Pull to refresh is not working with Tab layout](https://github.com/GeekyAnts/NativeBase/issues/2178)